# Using psycopg2, how can I receive output from `Raise Info 'foo'` in real time from psycopg2 query execution

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, python-3.10

I have a long-running stored procedure that uses `Raise Info 'some status'` to keep the client informed. The following is a dummy function illustrating this:

```
Create or Replace Function Test_Raise() Returns void language plpgsql as $$
    DECLARE
        _X Text;
    Begin
        Raise Info 'Test 1 %', clock_timestamp();
        _x = pg_sleep(2);
        Raise Info 'Test 2 %', clock_timestamp();
        _x = pg_sleep(10);
        Raise Info 'Test 3 %', clock_timestamp();
    End;$$;
```

Calling `select Test_Raise();` in `psql` or a client like `DataGrip` shows the output as each `Raise` statement is executed. With psycopg2 (v2.9.9) it all displays at the end.

I have set the `conn.notices` and `conn.notifier` with objects that display output add soon as something is appended, and only the `notices` property produces results, and only when the query completes (they are all appended to the list at the end).

Any suggestions as to how to get real-time information from the `raise` statement would be greatly appreciated.

For those who don't know `psycopg2` very well, here is the trivial code to reproduce:

```
import psycopg2


class Log(list):
    def append(self,item):
        print(item)
        super().append(item)


conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='jade_replica', host='10.158.1.63', port=32222, user='postgres', password='moozle')
conn.notifies = Log()
conn.notices = Log()
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from test_raise()")
```

Comment: As you have discovered SQL is **non-interactive**, even the [Notify](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html) SQL Command only generates its output when a transaction completes. Perhaps you could implement an [autonomous transaction](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/implementing-autonomous-transactions-in-postgres/).

Comment: (1) It's latest psyopg2 (2.99, iirc). (2) The code is bordering on trivial and unlikely yo do anything but bloat the question. Anyone who can answer this will understand exactly the 5 or so lines being executed.

Comment: @Belayer While SQL is not defined to have async communication channels, Postgres *does*, as specifically noted in the question. These async channels are supported by `psql` and `DataGrip`, at the least, and probably a vast number of other clients. The limitation is (apparently) `psycopg2`, and the solution seems to be to use `psycopg` (which is v3),. as noted in my answer below.

Comment: Yes, so trivial that it omits this: *Because of the way sessions interact with notifications (see NOTIFY documentation), you should keep the connection in autocommit mode if you wish to receive or send notifications in a timely manner.* from here [Asynchronous notifications](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/advanced.html#async-notify).

Comment: If you had actually tested your solution, you would find it did not work. For those who wonder why, it's (a) because auto-commit is a client-level option that executes  at the statement level (and there's only one statement), (b) postgres stored procedures are atomic, and (c) the suggested solution is for 'NOTIFY' events not the messages generated via the `raise` statement, which for some reason is treated differently in psycopg2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is a limitation of `psycopg2`; the best solution is to use `psycopg` instead (which is actually version 3). It is more or less compatible with `psycopg2` but has much better handling of asynchronous comms from the server via the `add_notice_handler` method.